# Solr to Application Insights

Tags: solr, log4j, azure-application-insights

How can I configure Solr logs to get sent to Azure Application Insights?

I see can use a Log4J appender.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-trace-logs

Solr is an open source project, and I don't compile it myself, I just use the distribution.

How can I drop in Application Insights/Log4J appender, without recompiling having installed the SDK?
I just want to configure the logs to get sent to application insghts, for effectively a 3rd party application.
And configure the instrumentation key.

I'm normally a C# dev, but familiar with Log4Net. So appologies if this is simple in Java Log4J. Not been able to find a post for this scenario so posting here.

Using Solr 6.6.

Comment: Have you seen [Configuring Logging](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/configuring-logging.html) in the Solr reference guide? It's using log4j2, and you can add any .jars in the lib directories defined in your solr configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, yes I read that page, but didn't see anything on referencing other jars? I presume possible, but can't see a detailed guide.

Comment: See [Lib directives in solrconfig](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html) for how to give specific paths to load jars from

Comment: thanks, that link was broken but found the page - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes a lot less configuration than you'd expect, and most of the info is hidden away in the link that you've already got: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-trace-logs

First, go download the jar files from https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/releases. You'll want `applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2-2.3.0` and `applicationinsights-core-2.3.0`. Put these in the server/lib folder and Solr will load them automatically for you.

Next you''ll need to add a new appender for app insights into your log4j.properties file

```
# Appinsights
log4j.appender.aiAppender=com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender
log4j.appender.aiAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.aiAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p (%t) [%X{collection} %X{shard} %X{replica} %X{core}] %c{1.} %m%n
```

You also need to add this `aiAppender` to the `log4j.rootLogger` list in the same file (it'll probably look something like this:  `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, CONSOLE, aiAppender`)

Finally, you need an ApplicationInsights.xml file, which you can get an example of from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started#2-add-the-application-insights-sdk-for-java-to-your-project

Drop this in the server/resources folder, set your instrumentation key and you're good to go!

Comment: Any ideas how to do it in solr 7.5 which uses log4j2 ? assumed i needed to do similar with the lib folder then configure log4j2.xml but i always get ERROR Error processing element ApplicationInsightsAppender ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND

Comment: For Solr 8.1 which also uses log4j2 seems to work with
Appender:
<ApplicationInsightsAppender name="aiAppender" />
Loggers>AsyncRoot:
<AppenderRef ref="aiAppender"/>

Plus using the log4j2 JAR files in the lib folder.
See here for more details 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-trace-logs