# Solr 7.5 Log to application insights?

Tags: azure, solr, log4j, log4j2, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get my solr to log to application insights, solr is running in docker but i tried similar to this ...

[Solr to Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438572/solr-to-application-insights)

This however is using an older version of solr that uses log4j not log4j2.

I've tried downloading the insights errors into a folder (/opt/solr/server/lib) and loading them via plugins (the logs suggest the jar's are loaded - but i still get an error about by log4j2.xml config ... saying the class for the insights appender cannot be found,

Config is as followes ..

```xml
<Configuration packages="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v2"> 
  <Appenders>
    <ApplicationInsightsAppender name="aiAppender" instrumentationKey="key-here"> 
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>
          %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p (%t) [%X{collection} %X{shard} %X{replica} %X{core}] %c{1.} %m%n
        </Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </ApplicationInsightsAppender>
 ......
```

Any ideas where im going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe below is the confguration for log4j:

```
<appender name="aiAppender" 
         class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
        <param name="instrumentationKey" value="[APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_KEY]" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value ="trace" />
      <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
    </root>
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-trace-logs

try this and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's for the old version of log4j, solr 7.5 uses log4j2